# Error trabajando con Kivy: NameError: name 'ListProperty' is not defined

Tags: python, lista, kivy

Tengo un error en un programa que estoy tratando de pasar a Kivy. Tengo una función: `askquestions(self,indexquestionlist)` que, como se ve, requiere el parámetro `indexquestionlist`. Este parámetro es el retorno producido por otra función:`indexquestions(AnswerDatelist, Atlist)`. Los dos parámetros de esta función, `AnswerDatelist` y `Atlist` son producidos por esta expresión: `wordlist, IDQuestionlist, Questionlist, Answerlist, AnswerDatelist, Atlist = Entitylist_matrix()`, pero esta última función no creo que me dé problemas.

Para abordar su resolución he optado por crear una lista llamada `indexquestionlist` dentro de la clase `VentanaTanda`

```
class VentanaTanda(Screen):
    score = NumericProperty()
    indexquestionlist = ListProperty([])
```

(ver más abajo en código python)

El problema es que me da el error: *NameError: name 'ListProperty' is not defined*. Para más detalles:
  *File "C:...\main.py", line 255, in VentanaTanda
     indexquestionlist = ListProperty([])
 NameError: name 'ListProperty' is not defined*

Según [la documentación](https://kivy.org/docs/api-kivy.properties.html) esta propiedad pertenece a `class kivy.properties.ListProperty` He probado a incluir esta expresión donde pongo todos los "import" pero me da error.
**El alcance de mi pregunta es conseguir tener una variable, indexquestionlist, que sea una lista que salga como retorno de la función `indexquestions`**. Después seguirá habiendo fallos pero no pretendo que me paséis el programa entero a kivy. Con conseguir lo dicho anteriormente me doy por satisfecho.

main.py:

```
from kivy.app import App
from kivy.lang import Builder
from kivy.properties import NumericProperty
from kivy.uix.screenmanager import ScreenManager, Screen

from random import randint
from datetime import datetime, date, time, timedelta


#DECLARACIÓN DE FUNCIONES

def Date_secondsnow():
    now = datetime.now()
    Datesecondsnow = now.second + now.minute*60 + now.hour*60*60 + now.day*24*60*60 + now.month*30*24*60*60 + now.year*365*24*60*60
    return Datesecondsnow

def addtext(text, a):
    a = a + "\n" + text
    return a

#CARGAMOS LOS DATOS
#Abrimos el archivo
#Pasamos el archivo de txt a formato de listas de entidad.
def txt_Entitylist():
    f = open("Questions CE.txt","r")
    filechain = f.read()
    #Atención! Asegurate que no hay un caracter EOF después del ultimo "0"
    #Saco Entitylist
    Entitylist = []
    Entitylist = filechain.split("|")
    f.close()
    return Entitylist

#Función para convertir un txt en una matriz

def Entitylist_matrix():
    Entitylist = txt_Entitylist()
    #Partimos Entitylist en una lista de palabras (wordlist)
    wordlist = []
    partx = []
    for x in Entitylist:
        partx = x.split("^")
        a = 0
        while a < len(partx):
            wordlist = wordlist + [partx[a]]
            a = a + 1
    #IDQuestionlist
    IDQuestionlist = []
    i = 0
    while i<len(wordlist):
        IDQuestionlist = IDQuestionlist + [wordlist[i]]
        i = i + 5
    #Questionlist
    Questionlist = []
    i = 1
    while i<len(wordlist):
        Questionlist = Questionlist + [wordlist[i]]
        i = i + 5
    #Answerlist
    Answerlist = []
    i = 2
    while i<len(wordlist):
        Answerlist = Answerlist + [wordlist[i]]
        i = i + 5
    #AnswerDatelist
    AnswerDatelist = []
    i = 3
    while i<len(wordlist):
        AnswerDatelist = AnswerDatelist + [wordlist[i]]
        i = i + 5
    #Atlist (Delta time)
    Atlist = []
    i = 4
    while i<len(wordlist):
        Atlist = Atlist + [wordlist[i]]
        i = i + 5
    return wordlist, IDQuestionlist, Questionlist, Answerlist, AnswerDatelist, Atlist

#Función que guarda los datos
def matrix_txt(IDQuestionlist, Questionlist, Answerlist, AnswerDatelist, Atlist):
    file=open('Questions CE.txt','w') #Si lo abres en modo "a", añade datos sin borrar los que ya estaban
    #1º Quitamos los espacios en blanco que nos sobran de AnswerDatelist y Atlist
    #i = 0
    #while i<len(Atlist):
    #    a = str(Atlist[i])
    #    Atlist[i] = a.strip()
    i = 0
    while i<len(Atlist):
          file.write(""+IDQuestionlist[i]+""+"^")
          file.write(""+Questionlist[i]+""+"^")
          file.write(""+Answerlist[i]+""+"^")
          file.write(" "+str(AnswerDatelist[i]).strip()+" "+"^")
          if i + 1 == len(Atlist):
              file.write(" "+str(Atlist[i]).strip()+" ")
          else:
              file.write(" "+str(Atlist[i]).strip()+" "+"^")
          i = i + 1
    file.close()








#Función para forzar preguntas (se preguntaran las preguntas aunque no haya pasado el tiempo necesario para hacerlas)
def ask_all():
    i = 0
    answer = 0
    while i<len(Atlist) and answer !="exit":
          #Mostrar pregunta
          print(Questionlist[i]) 
          while answer != "s" and answer != "exit":
                print("Una vez que hayas pensado la respuesta debes pulsar s (show answer)")
                answer = input()
          if answer == "s":
            #Inicializo la variable AnswerDatelist ¿y que hay de Atlist?
            if int(AnswerDatelist[i]) == 0:
               AnswerDatelist[i] = Date_secondsnow()
            if int(Atlist[i]) == 0:
                Atlist[i] = 1
            print(Answerlist[i])
            print("A continuación pulsa g (good) si la respuesta que has pensado ha sido buena, o w (wrong) si has fallado")
            print("El valor de Atlist es:", Atlist)
            while answer !="w" and answer != "g" and answer!="exit":
                    answer = input()#¿La primera vez que se pasa por el  bucle se ejecuta lo que está adentro?
                    if answer == "w":
                       Atlist[i] = 1
                       AnswerDatelist[i] = Date_secondsnow()
                    if answer == "g":
                       if 2*int(Atlist[i]) > Date_secondsnow() - int(AnswerDatelist[i]):
                          Atlist[i] = 2*int(Atlist[i])
                       else:
                           Atlist[i] = 2*(Date_secondsnow() - int(AnswerDatelist[i]))
                    else:
                        print("Debes pulsar una 'g' o una 'w'")
          i = i + 1




#Función para calcular el tiempo que queda para hacer nuevas preguntas
          #Qué pasa cuando el resto es negativo?

#Función para preguntar las preguntas que tocan:
def ask():
    indexquestionlist = indexquestions(AnswerDatelist, Atlist)
    askquestions(indexquestionlist)

#Función que pregunta las preguntas que tocan de dos en dos:
def ask_2():
    indexquestionlist = indexquestions(AnswerDatelist, Atlist)
    while indexquestionlist != []:
        indexquestionlist_2 = []
        indexquestionlist = indexquestions(AnswerDatelist, Atlist)
        if len(indexquestionlist)>= 2:
            indexquestionlist_2 = [indexquestionlist[0]] + [indexquestionlist[1]]
            askquestions(indexquestionlist_2)
        if len(indexquestionlist) == 1:
            indexquestionlist_2 = [indexquestionlist[0]]
            askquestions(indexquestionlist_2)
        if len(indexquestionlist) == 0:
            return -1
        indexquestionlist = indexquestions(AnswerDatelist, Atlist)



#Función para guardar datos desde línea de comandos
#def save():
#    matrix_txt(IDQuestionlist, Questionlist, Answerlist, AnswerDatelist, Atlist)

def indexquestions(AnswerDatelist, Atlist):
    #Primero preguntar las que tienen un AnswerDate = 0
        indexquestionlist = []
         #Recorremos la lista AnswerDatelist
        i = 0
        while i<len(AnswerDatelist):
            if int(AnswerDatelist[i]) == 0:
                indexquestionlist = indexquestionlist + [i]
            i = i + 1
    #Segundo preguntar las que toca preguntar ¿Cuáles son las que toca preguntar?
        #Las que tienen AnswerDate + At < Dateseconds now
        i = 0
        while i<len(AnswerDatelist):
            if int(AnswerDatelist[i]) + int(Atlist[i]) < Date_secondsnow():
                indexquestionlist = indexquestionlist + [i]
            i = i + 1
        indexquestionlist = list(set(indexquestionlist)) #Asi me aseguro de que no hay ninguna pregunta repetida
        return indexquestionlist

#indexquestionlist = [] Pensé en definirlo aquí pero nos sigue dando el error de acontinuación. Definimos "indexquestionlist" porque si no, nos da el error File "design.kv", line 99, in <module>   on_release: tanda.askquestions(indexquestionlist) NameError: name 'indexquestionlist' is not defined
wordlist, IDQuestionlist, Questionlist, Answerlist, AnswerDatelist, Atlist = Entitylist_matrix()
indexquestionlist = indexquestions(AnswerDatelist, Atlist)

Builder.load_file('design.kv')


class MyScreenManager(ScreenManager):
    def __init__(self):
        super(MyScreenManager, self).__init__()


class VentanaMenu(Screen):
    def save(self):
        matrix_txt(IDQuestionlist, Questionlist, Answerlist, AnswerDatelist, Atlist)


class VentanaNuevas(Screen):
    def tuq(self): #time until question
    #Cómo calcular el tiempo que queda?
        tuq_difference = []
        tuq_difference_magnitude = []
        tuq_difference_scaleoftime = []
        chaintuq =""    
        i = 0
        while i<len(Atlist):
            tuq_difference = tuq_difference + [int(AnswerDatelist[i])+int(Atlist[i]) - Date_secondsnow()]
            i = i + 1
        i = 0
        while i<len(tuq_difference):
            if tuq_difference[i] < 60:
                tuq_difference_magnitude = tuq_difference_magnitude + [tuq_difference[i]]
                tuq_difference_scaleoftime = tuq_difference_scaleoftime + ["segundos"]
            if tuq_difference[i] < 3600 and tuq_difference[i] > 60:
                tuq_difference_magnitude = tuq_difference_magnitude + [tuq_difference[i]/60]
                tuq_difference_scaleoftime = tuq_difference_scaleoftime + ["minutos"]
            if tuq_difference[i] > 3600 and tuq_difference[i] < 3600*24:
                tuq_difference_magnitude = tuq_difference_magnitude + [tuq_difference[i]/3600]
                tuq_difference_scaleoftime = tuq_difference_scaleoftime + ["horas"]
            if tuq_difference[i] > 3600*24 and tuq_difference[i] < 3600*24*30:
                tuq_difference_magnitude = tuq_difference_magnitude + [tuq_difference[i]/(3600*24)]
                tuq_difference_scaleoftime = tuq_difference_scaleoftime +[ "días"]
            if tuq_difference[i] > 3600*24*30 and tuq_difference[i] < 3600*24*30*12:
                tuq_difference_magnitude = tuq_difference_magnitude + [tuq_difference[i]/(3600*24*30)]
                tuq_difference_scaleoftime = tuq_difference_scaleoftime + ["meses"]
            if tuq_difference[i] > 3600*24*30*12:
                tuq_difference_magnitude = tuq_difference_magnitude + [tuq_difference[i]/(3600*24*30*12)]
                tuq_difference_scaleoftime = tuq_difference_scaleoftime + ["años"]
            i = i + 1
        i = 0
        while i<len(Atlist):
            if tuq_difference[i] < 0:
                chaintuq = addtext("Ya te toca contestar a la pregunta "+IDQuestionlist[i], chaintuq)
            else:
                chaintuq = addtext("Para preguntar "+IDQuestionlist[i]+"quedan "+str(tuq_difference_magnitude[i])+" "+tuq_difference_scaleoftime[i], chaintuq)
            i = i + 1
        self.ids['label4'].text = chaintuq


class VentanaTanda(Screen):
    score = NumericProperty()
    indexquestionlist = ListProperty([])
#Función que muestra que preguntas hacer
    def indexquestions(self,AnswerDatelist, Atlist):
    #Primero preguntar las que tienen un AnswerDate = 0
        indexquestionlist = []
         #Recorremos la lista AnswerDatelist
        i = 0
        while i<len(AnswerDatelist):
            if int(AnswerDatelist[i]) == 0:
                indexquestionlist = indexquestionlist + [i]
            i = i + 1
    #Segundo preguntar las que toca preguntar ¿Cuáles son las que toca preguntar?
        #Las que tienen AnswerDate + At < Dateseconds now
        i = 0
        while i<len(AnswerDatelist):
            if int(AnswerDatelist[i]) + int(Atlist[i]) < Date_secondsnow():
                indexquestionlist = indexquestionlist + [i]
            i = i + 1
        indexquestionlist = list(set(indexquestionlist)) #Asi me aseguro de que no hay ninguna pregunta repetida
        return indexquestionlist

    #Función que hace pregutas
    def askquestions(self,indexquestionlist): #Todavía no he terminado esta función
        i = 0
        answer = 0
        while i<len(indexquestionlist) and answer != "exit": #Recorro el vector indexquestionlist
        #Mostrar pregunta
              a = ""
              a = addtext(Questionlist[indexquestionlist[i]],a)
              self.ids['label1'].text = a
              while answer != "s" and answer != "exit":
                    a =""
                    a = addtext("Una vez que hayas pensado la respuesta debes pulsar s (show answer)",a)
                    answer = input()
              if answer == "s":
            #Inicializo la variable AnswerDatelist ¿y que hay de Atlist?
                if int(AnswerDatelist[indexquestionlist[i]]) == 0:
                   AnswerDatelist[indexquestionlist[i]] = Date_secondsnow()
                if int(Atlist[indexquestionlist[i]]) == 0:
                    Atlist[indexquestionlist[i]] = 1
                print(Answerlist[indexquestionlist[i]])
                print("A continuación pulsa g (good) si la respuesta que has pensado ha sido buena, o w (wrong) si has fallado")
                print("El valor de Atlist es:", Atlist)
                while answer !="w" and answer != "g" and answer!="exit":
                        answer = input()#¿La primera vez que se pasa por el  bucle se ejecuta lo que está adentro?
                        if answer == "w":
                           Atlist[indexquestionlist[i]] = 1
                           AnswerDatelist[indexquestionlist[i]] = Date_secondsnow()
                        if answer == "g":
                           if 2*int(Atlist[indexquestionlist[i]]) > Date_secondsnow() - int(AnswerDatelist[indexquestionlist[i]]):
                              Atlist[indexquestionlist[i]] = 2*int(Atlist[indexquestionlist[i]])
                           else:
                               Atlist[indexquestionlist[i]] = 2*(Date_secondsnow() - int(AnswerDatelist[indexquestionlist[i]]))
                        if answer !="w" and answer !="g":
                            print("Debes pulsar una 'g' o una 'w'")
              i = i + 1

    #def showquestion(self):
     #   with open("question.txt", "r") as f:
      #      filetext = f.read()
       #     self.ids['label1'].text = filetext

    def showanswer(self):
        with open("answer.txt", "r") as f:
            filetext = f.read()
            self.ids['label2'].text = filetext


class myApp(App):
    def build(self):
        return MyScreenManager()

    def on_pause(self):
        return True

    def on_resume(self):
        pass


if __name__ in ('__main__', '__android__'):
    myApp().run()
```

design.kv:

```
#:import WipeTransition kivy.uix.screenmanager.WipeTransition


<MyScreenManager>:
    transition: WipeTransition()
    VentanaMenu:
    VentanaNuevas:
    VentanaTanda:

<VentanaMenu>:
    name: 'menu'
    id: menu
    AnchorLayout:
        BoxLayout:
            anchor_x: 'center'
            anchor_y: 'center'
            padding: 0,10,0,0
            spacing: 10
            size_hint:1, 0.25
            orientation: 'vertical'
            # Botones de presentación
            Button:
                id: button5
                text: "Tiempo para nuevas preguntas"
                on_release: app.root.current = 'nuevas'; app.root.get_screen('nuevas').tuq()
            Button:
                id: button6
                text: "Hacer tanda de preguntas"
                on_release: app.root.current = 'tanda'
            Button:
                id: button7
                text: "Salir"
                on_release: menu.save(), app.stop()

<VentanaTanda>:
    name: 'tanda'
    id: tanda
    BoxLayout:
        size: root.size
        orientation: 'vertical'
        padding: 20
        spacing: 0

        #label1 muestra la pregunta
        Label:
            id: label1
            color: 1,0,1,1
            canvas.before:
                Color:
                    rgba: 191/255.0, 144/255.0, 63/255.0, 1
                Rectangle:
                    size: self.size
                    pos: self.pos

        #label2 muestra la respuesta
        Label:
            id: label2
            color: 1,0,1,1
            canvas.before:
                Color:
                    rgba:  110/255.0, 191/255.0, 63/255.0, 1
                Rectangle:
                    pos:self.pos
                    size: self.size

        Label:
            id: label3
            color: 1,0,1,1
            text: str(tanda.score)
            canvas.before:
                Color:
                    rgba: 74/255.0, 25/255.0, 44/255.0, 1
                Rectangle:
                    pos:self.pos
                    size: self.size


        BoxLayout:
            padding: 0,10,0,10
            spacing: 10
            size_hint:1, 0.30
            orientation: 'horizontal'
            Button:
                id: button1
                text: "Mostrar respuesta"
                on_release: tanda.showanswer()
            Button:
                id: button2
                text: "Pregunta Acertada"
                on_release: tanda.score += 10

            Button:
                id: button3
                text: "Pregunta Fallada"
                on_release: tanda.score -= 5
            Button:
                id: button4
                text: "Mostrar pregunta"
                on_release: tanda.askquestions(tanda.indexquestionlist)

        #Botón Para volver al menu
        Button:
            size_hint:1, 0.25
            text: "Volver al menu"
            on_release: app.root.current = 'menu'

<VentanaNuevas>
    name: 'nuevas'
    id: nuevas
    BoxLayout:
        size: root.size
        orientation: 'vertical'
        padding: 20
        spacing: 10

        #label4 muestra el tiempo hasta las preguntas
        Label:
            id: label4
            color: 1,0,1,1
            canvas.before:
                Color:
                    rgba: 33/255.0, 127/255.0, 190/255.0, 1
                Rectangle:
                    pos:self.pos
                    size: self.size

        #Botón Para volver al menu
        Button:
            size_hint:1, 0.10
            text: "Volver al menu"
            on_release: app.root.current = 'menu'
```

También incluyo el fichero "Questions CE.txt" porque lo necesita la función `Entitylist_matrix()`
Questions CE.txt:

```
 CEP1 ^ ¿Cuando es aprobada la constitución española? ^ El 31 de octubre de 1978 ^ 63620252955 ^ 1 ^ CEP2 ^ ¿Cuando es ratificada la constitución española? ^ El 6 de diciembre de 1978 ^ 63620252997 ^ 1 ^ CEP3 ^ ¿Cuando es sancionada la CE? ^ El 27 de diciembre de 1978 ^ 63620253010 ^ 1 ^ CEP4 ^ ¿Por quién es aprobada la CE? ^ Por las cortes ^ 63619108582 ^ 2182800 ^ CEP5 ^ ¿Por quién es ratificada la CE? ^ Por el pueblo español ^ 63619107733 ^ 2186216 ^ CEP6.1 ^ ¿Por quién es sancionada la CE? ^ Por S.M el Rey ^ 63619108620 ^ 2182724 ^ CEP6.2 ^ ¿Ante quién es sancionada la CE? ^ Ante las Cortes ^ 63619108635 ^ 2182676 ^ CEP7.01 ^ ¿Cuántos títulos tiene la constitución? ^ 11 con el título preliminar ^ 0 ^ 0
```

Comment: Estoy echandole un vistazo con calma a tu código y me surge una duda, supuestamente (si comprendo lo que pretendes hacer) `indexquestions` debe retornar una lista con los índices ordenados en orden de aparición de las preguntas. Si haces `indexquestionlist = list(set(indexquestionlist))` eliminas duplicados pero **el orden se pierde** y por tanto la función es inutil dado que los conjuntos set() no tienen orden interno. Debes hacerlo todo en un solo ciclo, de esta forma evitas duplicados y no necesitas de set.

Answer (score 0):

El problema es que no estas importando la clase ListProperty como bién dices. El import debe ser:

```
from kivy.properties import ListProperty
```

Como también usas NumericProperty puedes hacer:

```
from kivy.properties import ListProperty, NumericProperty
```

Recuerda que para hacer uso del atributo `indexquestionlist` dentro de la clase debes usar `self.indexquestionlist`. Dado que tu código es largo dejo un ejemplo sencillo de un posible uso de una ListProperty:

```
from kivy.app import App
from kivy.uix.boxlayout import BoxLayout
from kivy.properties import ListProperty
from kivy.lang import Builder

from random import randint

Builder.load_string('''
<MyWidget>:
    orientation: 'vertical'
    Label:
        id: label1

    Button:
        size_hint: 1, 0.15
        text: 'Mostra nueva lista aleatoria'
        on_release: root.mostrarLista()
        '''
    )

class MyWidget(BoxLayout):
    lista = ListProperty()
    def __init__(self):
        super(MyWidget, self).__init__()

    def randomList(self):
        out = [str(randint(1,100)) for n in range(11)]
        self.lista = out

    def mostrarLista(self):
        self.randomList()
        text = '\n'.join(self.lista)
        self.ids.label1.text = text



class myApp(App):
    def build(self):
        return MyWidget()

if __name__ in ('__main__'):
    myApp().run()
```

Tenemos un Label y un botón. Al pulsar el botón llamamos al método mostrarLista que genera una lista de 10 números pseudoaleatorios del 1 al 100 que son almacenados en la ListProperty llamada `lista` mediante el método `ramdonList`. Posteriormente muestra la lista en la etiqueta.

Dependiendo del uso que le des a `indexquestionlist` también puedes crear una lista normal de Python como un atributo de instancia en el `__init__` (`self.indexquestionlist = []`). Si la lista **no va a interactuar de forma directa** con algún widget, sino que, por ejemplo, un método va a ir tomado items de ella y los va a mostrar en un label, esta forma es perféctamente válida.